# Category equivalence of sets and vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, category-theory

It seems to me that for a field $K$, the functor $\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Vec}_K$, sending a set to the free $K$-vector space on it, is a category equivalence. It is full and faithful because a linear map between vector spaces is uniquely determined by a map on bases, and it is essentially surjective because every vector space has a basis.

However I could not find any reference for this, so I doubt it is true. Could anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: @BabyDragon: You mean $\oplus_S$, not $\otimes_S$.

Comment: This functor is not full. For instance take the map $\oplus_S\mathbb{R}→\oplus_{S}\mathbb{R}$ defined by  $s\mapsto−s$. This does not come from any map of the form, $f:S\mapsto S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is in fact an abstract nonsense proof that $F$ is faithful but not full, just from considering the unit $\eta=$"insertion of generators" of the adjunction $ (F,U;\eta,\epsilon)$. This comes from dualizing the following result, which is Theorem $1$ in section $\mathrm{IV}.3$ in Mac Lane's *Categories for the Working Mathematician*.

> (i) $U$ is faithful iff every component $ϵ_a$ of the counit $ϵ$ is epi.
>     (ii) $U$ is full iff every $ϵ_a$ is a section.

Since $(U,F;ϵ^{op},η^{op})$ is also an adjunction, namely $A^{op}→X^{op}$, we see that $F$ is faithful iff $η$ is monic, and $F$ is full iff $η$ is a retraction.

Since the insertion of generators as a basis into a vector space is monic but not surjective, it follows that $F$ is faithful but not full.

But you are right that $F$ is essentially surjective, as every vector space is free.

Answer (score 5):

Your argument "because a linear map between vector spaces is uniquely determined by a map on bases" correctly shows the functor is faithful, but not full: given vector spaces with bases $(U, \{e_i\})$ and $(V,\{f_i\})$ not every linear map comes from a function of sets between $\{e_i\}$ and $\{f_i\}$.